# Какой корень в слове "объявление"?

Tags: морфология

Если -явл-, то какие слова однокоренные, если -объявл-, то как объяснить -Ъ-?

Answer (score 5):

Значит, отвечаю собственно на вопрос.
Есть два похода, оба признаются наукой. Первый (синхронический) рассмаривает состав слова в его современном состоянии, опуская исторические переразложения. Второй (диахронический), напротив, интересуется исторической грамматикой и морфологией.

Так, вот, согласно первому, слово "объявление" имеет корень "объяв(л)", а корневой Ъ объясняется исторической традицией, другими словами, "объявление" является словарным словом, исключением из правила, что корневой Ъ в исконно русских корнях не встречается. Однокоренное - **объявить**, появление "Л" на стыке корня и суффикса (морфеменом шве) рассматривается как чередование.
Этот подход обычно используют в школе.

Согласно диахроническому подходу, "объявление" имеет приставку "об", корень "яв", эпентический (от "эпентеза" - вставка) согласный "Л" и суффикс "ен". Однокоренными считаются **явь**, **явление**, **явный**, **появление** и т. д.
Этот подход используется в академических исследованиях по истории языка (исторической грамматике и фонетике).

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, корень *-явл-,* а *об-* приставка.

Однокоренные слова: *явление, появление, проявление, выявление, заявление*, образованные от них глаголы *являть, заявлять* и др., причастия *явленный, заявленный,* деепричастия *являя, заявляя.*

Answer (score 3):

Согласно **Морфемно-орфографическому словарю Н. А. Тихонова** корень в слове "объявление" *объяв-/объявл.*

Сегодня приставка в этом корне уже не выделяется, так как этот глагол в своем значении слишком далеко отошел от слов явиться, появиться, появление, заявление. Чтобы убедиться в этом, надо подобрать родственные слова и выделить общую часть, в которой заключено их значение: **объяв**ить, **объявл**ять, **объявл**яться, **объявл**енный (прилагательное).

Как видно на примерах, из слова в слово повторяется часть объяв-/объявл—, в которой происходит чередование согласных в/вл. Значит, это корень.

Морфемный состав такой:

объявл/ени/е  [й/э]

объявл — корень

ений — суффикс

е — окончание

Comment: если -объявл-, то как объяснить -Ъ-?

Comment: Ъ- входит в корень. Исторически здесь приставка об. А на стыке приставки, оканчивающуюся  на согласную, и корня перед  е, ю, я пишется твердый знак.

Comment: э — окончание чего?

Comment: Хотел написать е.